# Make something auto update like Facebook chat

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Before Reading on, what I want to achieve is make something update inside a div automatically without refreshing a div. (kinda like Facebook chat, I don't see chat flicker or blink when a new message is added,but just add new data seamlessly.)**

In my Index I have the following markup:

```
<div>   
  <?php
    if($_SESSION['Login']==1){
      include_once('Branch_Pages/Bar_in.php');
      }
    else{
      include_once('Branch_Pages/Bar_out.php');
      }
  ?>
</div>
```

The Sesssion Variable Login is set to "1" When a user is logged in,
and in Bar_in.php I have a search box that gives suggestions based on a data-list generated by php.

```
<datalist  id="StudentList">
  <?php
    for($x=0;$x<$_SESSION['num_rows'];$x++){
        echo'
                <option value="'.$Enroll_F_name[$x].' '.$Enroll_L_name[$x].'" data-id="'.$enroll_data_No[$x].'" label="'.$_SESSION['Enroll_Index_num'][$x].'">
        ';
    }
  ?>
</datalist>
```

How can I update the datalist automatically without refreshing the div(since refreshing makes the Bar flicker) or without making it blink when it refreshes?

Comment: ajax, poll the server.

Comment: this question is already tagged with ajax USE THAT :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a lot to learn here.

1. After your page loads, start polling the server for new data, this basically means firing a request every few seconds (5,10,15,30, whatever makes sense for your app) [Here is some info on polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)
2. That request should return the data you need, preferably in a JSON object, or some other format that is easy for you to parse with javascript.
3. Turn the JSON data into dom objects representing what is being repeated in your datalist
4. use jQuery to append the objects to the datalist children array

Comment: That'll work. It's going to be excessive on bandwidth, but will still work and be achievable in your time constraints.